# Clusterização no R

Tags: r, data, dplyr, k-means

Galera, preciso fazer a clusterização dessa base de dados e depois fazer a predição.... Gostaria de saber, como eu poderia fazer a substituição de maneira correta nesse caso ?

Qual tipo de clusterização se encaixaria melhor?

Eu sou iniciante na área de dados e estou tentando resolver essa bucha ai, pois acredito que será um grande desafio para meu aprendizado.

Para reforçar: Gostaria de transformar os dados em números para que eu pudesse realizar uma leitura dele através do kmeans, por exemplo.... Mas aceito sugestões.

[image: formato dos dados no R]

Comment: Comece pela função por ver a `hclust`. E, por favor, não poste dados dessa maneira, *nunca* um ficheiro gráfico, ponha a saída de `dput(dados)`.

Comment: Opa, valeu Rui. É que este foi meu primeiro post...

Answer (score 0):

Apenas com o que você descreveu na pergunta fica difícil te dar uma resposta pontual. Sugiro que da próxima vez, ou caso esta resposta não seja satisfatória, explique um pouco o que a base de dados descreve.

A primeira coisa é fazer um trabalho de pré-processamento. Isso vai depender do tipo de algoritmo que você deseja implementar. Mas, caso seja um algoritmo como o K-Means, identificar os outliers e fazer algum certo tipo de imputação é quase que essencial. Afinal, ele se baseia na média.

O algoritmo do k-means é um dos 10 algoritmos mais usados no âmbito de mineração de dados ([link](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj6xq36uYXXAhUKgJAKHY8_AQkQFggxMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.uvm.edu%2F~icdm%2Falgorithms%2F10Algorithms-08.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2rkEXkSgpNLQfIEFxSFtp8)), e já foi inventado faz um tempo. Sabendo disso, acho que seria um ótimo começo trabalhar com esse algoritmo, mas agrupando séries temporais. Séries temporais são dados que tem parâmetros em função do tempo. No seu caso, uma ideia é que dá para fazer é tentar agrupar semanas com comportamentos similares entre si. Isso você pode fazer com diferentes tipos de atributos. Dá para ver quais são as semanas que possuem um comportamento similar no que se refere a `order_status`, `price`, etc.

Outro algoritmo bom para quem está começando é o DBSCAN, que é um um algortimo de densidade (o k-means é *prototype-base*, não sei como traduzir). Ele é bem simples e você nem precisa se preocupar com os outliers, pois é bem provável que eles sejam descartados. Mas, eu deixo o trabalho de ver onde implementar com você, que tem uma noção melhor de onde veio essa base de dados.

Boa sorte.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se o k-means seria a melhor opção para fazer mineração de dados em séries temporais, dado que ele assume independência entre as observações.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta galera pessoal, acabei deixando de lado... Eram dados de venda de um grande ecommerce brasileiro